# Image autoencoder w/o thousands of dense neurons? prevent large model

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, keras, tensorflow

I am trying to get around producing large models. If my desired output is a 120x100 image, then do I need a 120*100=`12,000` neuron dense layer preceding it?

```py
    ...
    model.add(Dense(120*100))) #<--- mandatory?
    model.add(Reshape((120, 100)))
    return model
```

The model size comes out to 5GB+ if I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need such a projection if you are using **only** dense layers for your model (i.e. a multilayer perception (MLP)). You can simply have a convolutional autoencoder, where the layers are convolutions and max pooling, and therefore the number of parameters is drastically reduced with respect to an MLP.

You can check [Keras' tutorial on autoencoders](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html), specifically the section "Convolutional autoencoders" for an example.

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction